# Can i run Erlang without local admin rights on Windows?

Tags: erlang

I have a machine which doesn't give me local admin rights. Is it still possible to run erlang on it, as I cannot run a windows .exe installer to install erlang?

Comment: Is this a question? If it is, I must have missed it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right, it was very badly worded by me. I have amended the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy erl.exe (plus the runtime system and all the libraries you need) from another installation and run it without the need to install. As long as you are allowed to execute files it should be okay.

Comment: Nice! I was a bit unspecific, glad you figured it out. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for not being as smart as Zubair, 
but I would like to know exactly how to do this.
I do not have admin privilege, cannot run installers, and cannot copy files to C:\WINDOWS.
In particular, I cannot write to C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS or C:\WINDOWS\system32.

How do I get a list of exactly what libraries are required by the various erlang executables ?

I have all the MS redistributable libraries and manifests,
but I don't know where to put them to make it work.
The redistributable library structure has directories such as
Microsoft.VC90.ATL, Microsoft.VC90.CRT, etc. Each directory contains relevant dlls and a  manifest.

Do I copy all the contents into the ERL_HOME\bin directory or ERL_HOME\erts-x.y.z\bin or ERL_HOME\erts-x.y.z\lib ?
or leave them in some other directory and put those entries in the PATH ?
or do I need to build the paths implied by the manifests (i.e. where they would be copied into the WinSxS cache) using hashes and version numbers in the paths, then put those entries in the PATH ?

Comment: It was quite a while ago that I got this working but I'll try to remember. First I created an Erlang install on a machine which had local admin rights, and then I just zipped it up. Then I got 7Zip and crated a self extracting executable. Running this extracted Erlang onto another machine and ran erl.exe. Did that help?

Comment: No, I assume you already have the relevant MS C dlls installed on your target machine. The Erlang installer tries to put these dlls under c:\windows, presumably by running the MS redistributable library installer (vcredist_x86.exe) available from MSDN. I have these libraries from another machine, but if Erlang expects them in the absolute path under c:\windows, then I am stuck. I'll try to read the manifests inside the erlang exe's....

Comment: I downloaded the [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool and ran it on erl.exe. That shows there is an embedded manifest dependency on a hardwired side-by-side (SxS) dll located at: c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_e6967989\MSVCR80.DLL I don't see any way around this (that's probably the idea :)

Comment: I'll try to dig out my erlang runner and get you an answer soon... buzz me if you don't hear from me though :)